# Show all categories, but not one specific

Tags: php, wordpress

Using Wordpress I am trying to show all posts except posts within one category (named *Aktuelt*). I am not sure how I should solve this problem. Been looking into excerpt, but not sure if that's the way to do it.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => '6',
    'post_taxonomy' => 'any',
);
```

Could you please provide a working solution? Or ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `cat` paraemeter to exclude posts from a specific category. Just add a minus sign in front of the category **ID**.

```
'cat' => -1, // This will exclude category 1
```

If you just have the name of the category, you can use `get_term_by()` to get the ID.

```
// Outside your arguments
$category = get_term_by( 'name', 'Aktuelt', 'category' );

// Inside your arguments
'cat' => -' . $category->term_id,
```

### EDIT

You can also use a `tax_query` and set the field parameter to name inside the `tax_query`, but there is a bug if a term has more than one word or a special character in the name. So you should avoid using term names with a `tax_query`

Comment: Thank you. I used `'cat' => -1`, and that solved the problem :)

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)